# Nuevo dataFrame filtrado a partir de uno original

Tags: python, pandas

Quiero generar un nuevo Df que muestre una única vez los valores repetidos en la columna 'Matriculas', asignándole los valores de 'Rutas'.

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_excel('Matriculas.xlsx')
print(df1)
```

Y el dataframe es así

```
df1= 
    Matriculas   Rutas  
0   123AB        1
1   456BC        2
2   789CD        3
3   123AB        3
4   456BC        4
5   789CD        5
6   456BC        8
7   789CD        9
```

La salida debe sera algo así como:

```
df2= 
    Matriculas   Rutas  
0   123AB        1,3
1   456BC        2,4,8
2   789CD        3,5,9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un `groupby()` te permite agrupar las matrículas iguales. Al resultado le puedes aplicar una función que resuma la información que quieres como "agregado" para cada matrícula. En tu caso quieres una lista de las rutas, por lo que podría servirte lo siguiente:

```
df2 = df1.groupby("Matriculas")["Rutas"].apply(list)
```

y sale:

```
Matriculas
123AB       [1, 3]
456BC    [2, 4, 8]
789CD    [3, 5, 9]
Name: Rutas, dtype: object
```

Si no te gusta tenerlas como listas y prefieres una cadena de texto con las rutas separadas por comas:

```
df2 = df1.groupby("Matriculas")["Rutas"].apply(
                              lambda l: ", ".join(str(ruta) for ruta in l))
```

y saldría:

```
Matriculas
123AB       1, 3
456BC    2, 4, 8
789CD    3, 5, 9
Name: Rutas, dtype: object
```

En ambos casos el resultado es una Serie. Si quieres tener un dataframe, bastaría hacer:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2).reset_index()
```

[image: Resultado]